# getting error generating large excel from SQL datatable in sharepoint designer 2010 through code

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, epplus

Problem : Want to generate Excel from the datatable.
          Created Workbook.Worksheet using OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage and Writing it to Excel using GetAsByteArray.

Same code works for lesser no of rows Eg. as I applied it on live server as select top 6000 * from table then it is working but if I make it as select * from table then it is throwing below mentioned exception.

```
    protected void FillExcel(DataTable table)
    {
        try
        {

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0 && table != null)
            {
                using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                {
                    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet ws;
                    ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("excelname_XYZ");

                    //worksheet name
                    int ColumnIndex = 0;                            //FillExcelData
                    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)       //FillExcelData column
                    {
                        ColumnIndex++;
                        ws.Cells[1, ColumnIndex].Value = col.ColumnName;
                    }
                    int rowIndex = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)             //FillExcelData rows
                    {
                        rowIndex++;
                        ColumnIndex = 0;
                        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                        {
                            ColumnIndex++;
                            ws.Cells[rowIndex + 1, ColumnIndex].Value = row[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    ColumnIndex = 0;
                    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                    {
                        ColumnIndex++;
                        ws.Cells[1, ColumnIndex].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        ws.Cells[1, ColumnIndex].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        ws.Cells[1, ColumnIndex].Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                        ws.Cells[1, ColumnIndex].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(31, 73, 124));
                    }

                    using (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange x = ws.Cells["A:AH"])
                    {
                        x.AutoFitColumns();
                    }


                    Byte[] fileBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
                    //Clear the response
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.Cookies.Clear();
                    //Add the header & other information                 
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
                    Response.CacheControl = "private";
                    Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
                    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
                    Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "cache");
                    Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "60");

                   string strFilename = "fileName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM").Trim() + ".xlsx";
                   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; " +
                    "filename=\"" + strFilename + ".xlsx\"; " +   //filename of excel
                    "size=" + fileBytes.Length.ToString()); 
                   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    //Write it back to the client                
                    Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('No Data Found for a specified date range.');", true);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

exception is at GetAsByteArray() method://

```
    System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 
    'System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib,     
    Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
    StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) at
    System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()    
    atSystem.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.DemandPermission   
    (IsolatedStorageScope scope) at  
    System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope
    scope, Evidence domainEv, Type domainEvidenceType, Evidence assemEv, Type
    assemblyEvidenceType, Evidence appEv, Type appEvidenceType) at
    System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope
    scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType) at
    System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope
    scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType) at
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder.
    .ctor() at    
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.GetDefaultIsolatedStorageFile()
    at          
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.
    CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount,
    String& fileName) at
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.EnsureIsolatedStoreStream() at
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary() at
    MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
    offset, Int32 count) at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write 
    (Byte [] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at
    MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer,
    Int32 offset, Int32 count) at 
    MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32    
    offset, Int32 count) at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream,
    Boolean flushEncoder) at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value) at
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.UpdateRowCellData(StreamWriter sw) at
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.SaveXml() at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.
    Save() at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save() at
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray(Boolean save) at
    ASP._3709a01c_9c4c_425e_a710_10d1095ce4ca_1735241207.FillExcel(DataTable
    table) in http://server/sitename/Report_Testing.aspx:line 125
    The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that
    failed was: System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission The
    first permission that failed was: The demand was for: The granted set of
    the failing assembly was: The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
    EPPlus, Version=2.9.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1
    The method that caused the failure was: Void UpdateRowCellData  
    (System.IO.StreamWriter) The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
    MyComputer The Url of the assembly that failed was:
    file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/2236/bin/EPPlus.DLL
```

Comment: How many rows/columns in the source table?

Comment: Rows 53455 and Columns 34 but same code is working on the dev server for same no of rows and columns.
Thanks for taking time..

Comment: Humm.. could it be the production server is more restrictive with ram usage per thread/connection?  Been a while since I dealt with that kind of stuff on a web server but that might be something to check out.

Comment: server ram is of 16GB and 4processors not sure what is happening.
Tried same code in asp.net web application in visual studio and it is working on same server. My observation is this code is not working in SharePoint environment. Do I need to make any configuration changes in SharePoint for larger import export of excel data.